# React-Router-Dom changing states of the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hi guys i have a problem. When I enter "dashboard" which is a private route it redirects me to "login" first then to dashboard. True and False are playing together. How can i fix it to not redirect me to login then to dashboard.

video example:
https://cdn.aboutluc.xyz/images/rc64kb6af92sswn3r4mv.mp4

code:

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react"

import { toast } from "react-toastify"

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate
} from "react-router-dom"

import {
  Login,
  Register,
  Dashboard,
} from "./Pages"

import {
  Navbar
} from "./Components"

import './App.css'
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css"
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

toast.configure()

const App = () => {

  const [ isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated ] = useState()

  const setAuth = (boolean) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(boolean)
  }

  const isAuth = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/verify", {
        headers: { JwtToken: localStorage.JwtToken }
      });

      const parseRes = await res.json();

      parseRes === true ? setIsAuthenticated(true) : setIsAuthenticated(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    isAuth()
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar setAuth={setAuth} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
        <Routes>

          <Route
            exact
            path="/login"
            element={
              isAuthenticated ? (
                <Navigate replace={true} to="/dashboard" />
              ) : (
                <Login setAuth={setAuth} />
              )
            }
          />

          <Route
            exact
            path="/register"
            element={
              isAuthenticated ? (
                <Navigate replace={true} to="/dashboard" />
              ) : (
                <Register setAuth={setAuth} />
              )
            }
          />

          <Route
            exact
            path="/dashboard"
            element={
              isAuthenticated ? (
                
                <Dashboard setAuth={setAuth} />
              ) : (
                <Navigate replace={true} to="/login" />
              )
            }
          />

        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: When you reload your page, it needs to send a request to verify your token and update "isAuthenticated" state, it will redirect to login page while it does that.
Maybe you could change the logic of your page by storing "isAuthenticated" on local storage and redirecting to login page when your back-end returns 401.

Comment: I think the problem is related to isAuthenticated state , second time you refresh the page it is still false and with an async request you find its value

Comment: @Andre then user can easily change it to true or false and app will broke

Comment: To avoid that you should add authentication headers to every user request. For example if your Dashboard displays the name of the user. When navigating to dashboard with an invalid JWTToken, the backend returns 401 to the name request, and your app redirects to login page.

Comment: I don't really think that is an good idea. I tried loading screen but it doesn't work either.

Comment: "When I enter "dashboard" which is a private route it redirects me to "login" first then to dashboard." - How is this a problem? This is how route protection works. If unauthenticated you get bounced to your auth route, authenticate, and redirect back to the route originally being accessed. What other than this are you expecting to occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible issue I see is the "gap" on the initial render where the `isAuthenticated` state is undefined and the `useEffect` hook callback to set that state hasn't run yet. If you attempt to directly access a protected route then regardless of *actual* auth status the code will bounce you to the login route.

For this you typically want to use the "third" indeterminant state to "hold" on either redirecting to auth or allowing access through to the protected component until the auth status is confirmed.

Abstract the auth status into auth layout components.

```
const AuthLayout = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
  if (isAuthenticated === undefined) return null; // or loading spinner, etc...

  return isAuthenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};

const AnonymousLayout = ({ isAuthenticated, to }) => {
  if (isAuthenticated === undefined) return null; // or loading spinner, etc...

  return isAuthenticated
    ? <Navigate to={to} replace />
    : <Outlet />;
};
```

User the layouts to guard/protect specific routes.

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    element={(
      <AnonymousLayout isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} to="/dashboard" />
    )}
  >
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login setAuth={setAuth} />} />
    <Route path="/register" element={<Register setAuth={setAuth} />} />
  </Route>
  <Route element={<AuthLayout isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />}>
    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard setAuth={setAuth} />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Note: You only ever call `isAuth` when the `App` component mounts. You may want to call this function or otherwise validate your auth token a little more often than this. Passing `isAuth` into the route wrappers and invoking also in an `useEffect` hook probably isn't a terrible idea.